# Swift 3 - Delegate always returns nil value

Tags: ios, swift3, tabs, uibutton, delegates

**UPDATED:**

I have designed custom tabBar using buttons. I have 3 tabs, 
First tab has **Messages** icon, Second has **Profile** icon and Third has **Photos** icon. For third tab button, I have used `uiCollectionView()` where I need to set images.

For the Third tab's ViewController,there is one condition that I need to check, before changing the `title` of the first tab button. If `messages` **JSON** array is not empty then set "new message" title on the first tab button, else the **Messages** icon won't change.

There is one ParentTabViewController which has these 3 tabs, I have used uiView, where I change the content according to the tab buttons pressed. I tried to access the values of 3rd tab in ParentTabViewController by using delegate, but the delegate is always nil. I did like this:

```
class ParentTabViewController: UIViewController,MessageDelegateProtocol{
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var tabBarButtons : [UIButton]!
@IBOutlet weak var firstTabButton: UIButton!
var MessageVC : UIViewController!
var ProfileVC : UIViewController!
var PhotosVC : UIViewController!
var viewControllers : [UIViewController]!
var message : String!
var selectedIndex:Int = 0
var photoVC = PhotosVC()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photoVC.newMessageDelegate = self

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)
    MessageVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "messagevc")
    ProfileVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile")
    PhotosVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photos")

    viewControllers = [MessageVC, ProfileVC, PhotosVC]
    tabBarButtons[selectedIndex].isSelected = true
    didPressTabs(tabBarButtons[selectedIndex])
}
@IBAction func didPressTabs(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let previousIndex = selectedIndex
    selectedIndex = sender.tag
    tabBarButtons[previousIndex].isSelected = false

    let previousVC = viewControllers[previousIndex]

    previousVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
    previousVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    previousVC.view.removeFromSuperview()

    sender.isSelected = true
    let presentVC = viewControllers[selectedIndex]
    addChildViewController(presentVC)

    presentVC.view.frame = contentView.bounds
    contentView.addSubview(presentVC.view)
    presentVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    if selectedIndex == 2{   // this is what I thought of doing.Correct me if wrong.
     //  check the condition 
     //   if messagesArray != nil
     //   set the first tab title "new message"
    }
    else{
     //    do not change the button image 
    }
}
func sendMessage(message : String)
{
    self.message = message
    print("message........", self.message, "\n\n")
}
}
```

**Here is the View Controller for 3rd tab:**

```
import UIKit
protocol MessageDelegateProtocol:class  {
 func sendMessage(message : String) 
}

class PhotosVC: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var userMessageArray = [UserMessageClass]()    // array of model class
var newMessage : String!
weak var newMessageDelegate : MessageDelegateProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    loadData()                        // function to get json reponse
}
// implement collectionView delegate and dataSource methods

func getData(newMsg : UserMessageClass)    //func to get values from model class
{
    newMessage = newMsg.messageString           // here I get the "new message" String
    newMessageDelegate?.sendMessage(message: newMessage)
}    enter code here

func loadData()
{
    // get json response. And pass the payload to UserMessageClass using that class's array
    userMessageArray.append(UserMessageClass(dict : jsonData))
    var msgData = UserMessageClass(dict: jsonData)
    getData(alarm: msgData)
}
}
```

I tried searching a lot about accessing tab buttons in another VC, but didn't find any nearby approach as such. Also I am not able to figure out why delegate is always nil. Suggestions or Help would be grateful. Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the following line.

```
let firstTab = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "parentVC") as! ParentViewController
```

You are probably expecting it to give you the instance of ParentViewController which you have setup initially. However, it will give you the instance of a newly initiated ParentViewController which is not what you want.

To counter this problem you can either make use of a delegate or completion block defined which will be defined inside your ParentViewController class.

**Update:**
Try adding `PhotosVC.newMessageDelegate = self` **under** the line

```
PhotosVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "photos")
```

Also change `var PhotosVC : UIViewController!` to `var photosVC: PhotosVC!`

This should work now.

Comment: Hi, Can u please show me how to do it by delegate. Because ParentViewController, gets loaded first and in that `MessagesVC()` is the first tab. When I click on 3rd tab, and check if `messages` json array is not nil, set the title to 1st tab. I thought of checking the condition in ParentVC, `if selectedIndex == 2 {  // do the checking }` and then set the title here. But I could not manage to get the values from MessagesVC in ParentVc. getting nil always. I tried by delegate but failed

Comment: Can you upload you project on github?

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question. Please check and suggest what's wrong

Comment: I am not able to do that. I am not getting any suggestion such as classname.delegate

Comment: I have updated the post. But dude you need to spend some more time in understanding the basics first.

Comment: I have used `var PhotosVC : UIViewController!` to initialise my tab's  View Controllers. I know I have problem understanding delegates, since I am learning it newly. Your way does not work.

Comment: Did you change `var PhotosVC : UIViewController!` to `var photosVC: PhotosVC!`. I am not talking about your understanding of delegates. The properties `MessageVC`, `ProfileVC` and `PhotosVC` are subclasses of UIViewController. Basically they are custom classes. If you use wrong class type you will never find the intended method on that class. You are also not using `UITabBarController` for some unknown reasons.

Comment: Yes I did that. But was getting nil value exception. So, I just tried `photosVC = PhotosVC as! PhotosVC` and than got the message value.

Comment: Could you join me in a chat ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153680/ios-discussion